# Pandas: modify cell values using method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, apply, assign, chaining

```
>>> df
  a b c ...
0 1 2
1 3 4
. ...
```

I want the `b` column to be doubled.
I know this method

```
>>> df['b'] *= 2
```

Can I do this in a method chaining style ? More pandorable I suppose !
Something like this.

```
>>> (df.drop('c', 1)
       .someMethodToReplaceBColumnValues())
```

I have lot of methods to clean the data and this is one of the operation and I am stuck at this.
I have come across, `replace`, `set_value` etc. But I am not able to figure out how.

I tried `apply` method also, but it returns only the column for which the operation is applied. So I am getting only the `b` column with apply method. How to approach further ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],
                   'b':[4,5,6],
                   'c':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

print (df.drop('c', 1).assign(b=df.b*2))
   a   b
0  1   8
1  2  10
2  3  12
```

---

```
print (df.drop('c', 1).apply(lambda x: x * 2 if x.name == 'b' else x))
   a   b
0  1   8
1  2  10
2  3  12
```

Comment: What if column name has a space ?

Comment: Unfortunately `assign` dont works with spaces in column names. So I add alternative solution with `lambda` and `apply`.

Comment: fantastic, this is what I was looking for. I knew `apply` would be proper choice, but didn't know how to use it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael you can put the statements into a dict and `df.assign(**statements)` to add/overwrite columns with spaces or other weird characters in their names.

Comment: @Maven - if need `assign` with space use `a = {'col space': df['col space'] * 2}` and then `print (df.assign(**a))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply, with a custom function:

```
def mult(x, columns):
    if x.name in columns:
        return x*2
    else:
        return x

print df.apply(mult, args=(['b', 'c'],))

   a   b  c
0  0   0  0
1  1   2  2
2  2   4  4
```

Do take into account that you pass a tuple as extra argument to the function in apply!

Comment: This is a good solution. Gives a legible code. Can we do this with lambda instead ?

Comment: Thanks Niels, I got the answer from @jezrael.